# Not able to click on link obtain using findElements method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is just a simple code to obtain all links from a particular section of a web page; click on those links get the title and return back to the parent page and repeat process for next one. But after clicking on 2 links I am getting error "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" Please refer code and let me know what I am missing.

I am able to open links in a new tab and get the title of child pages. But I want to open a link in the same tab.

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LinkTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\1\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");

        WebElement driverFooter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gf-BIG']"));
        WebElement footerC1 = driverFooter.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/ul[1]"));
        List<WebElement> links = footerC1.findElements(By.tagName("a"));


        for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
            links.get(i).click();
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            driver.navigate().back();


        }

    }
}
```

It should open all links and get the title and return to parent page for next iterator. Below is output and error,

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    [1550488224.725][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
    Practice Page
    REST API Tutorial
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
    System info: host: 'DS-SGH631RNL8', ip: '10.118.59.16', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:53075}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1), userDataDir=C:\Users\RUSHIK~1.KAD\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11700_2428}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=72.0.3626.109, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: e1a6bdd0b525d1c6e1d940a2ec156e51
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
        at test.LinkTest.main(LinkTest.java:23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting StaleElementReferenceException which comes when the element you are trying to access is no longer available in the dom or has become stale, to correct it you need to pick the elements again and then operate on it. You can modify your code like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\1\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");

WebElement driverFooter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gf-BIG']"));
WebElement footerC1 = driverFooter.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/ul[1]"));
List<WebElement> links = footerC1.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
driverFooter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gf-BIG']"));
footerC1 = driverFooter.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/ul[1]"));
    List<WebElement> newLinks = footerC1.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    newLinks.get(i).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

Comment: @ Sameer : I tried it but still i m getting same error. However, it works if use below code  for(int i = 1; i<links.size ; i++) {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gf-BIG']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul")).findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).click();

        driver.navigate().back();    . Why it is not working with earlier code when use List.

Comment: Have edited my answer, sorry i didn't see that you were using the last page element in the loop also, so you need to take those elements also again. Please check the updated code and let me know if it works

Comment: @ Sammer : Yes it worked. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: @ Sammer : Yes it worked. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: Happy to help you!! Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon on the answer